# Time complexity of the following recursive function

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following recursive function

```
int DoSomething(int n){
     if(n<=2) 
        return 1;
     else 
        return (DoSomething(floor(sqrt( n) )) + n);
}
```

Options are:-

1. O(n^2)
2. O(n log n) //all logs are with base 2
3. O(log n )
4. O(log log n )

Comment: as it is, this is a bad question. this is clearly a homework problem and you have not demonstrated any effort to solve it on your own. not that you likely care, but here's [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, this is not a homework problem, this was on GATE 2007 paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity function is (ignoring `floor` as it is asymptotically irrelevant):

[image]

We need to find `m` when the algorithm terminates, i.e. when:

[image]